# Protractor e2e test fullcalendar drag & drop

Tags: fullcalendar, protractor

I need to simulate a drag & drop on fullcalendar in the week view with protractor. I found [something](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fb46ec9bcd568510248831f11d43d0e2398cc606/spec/basic/actions_spec.js) with coordinates but I'd like a "no browser window dependent solution"... ther's also no way out on finding the exact starting cell in the week view by class or id ...or at least, I couldn't figure how to select a single cell of a row of a day because, using the Chrome's item selector, it seems every row has the same class `fc-widget-content` and cells are not "selectable" elements.

Are there any other chances?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is a little bit helpful (also very later ;). I also want to test my app with FullCalendar, but I'm using Cypress (similar to Protractor).

We plan items from an external list and assign it to a resource on a certain day/time in the FullCalendar (we use the scheduler plugin).

I found out that the `drag` and `drop` event is somehow intercepted by code, enriching it with for example properties of the event (like date, title and others). How I enriched this data is in the Cypress `trigger('drop', data)` command. Data is the evenData that is set by the `Draggable` class:

```
// Executed on the external list items, where every item we want to plan has class `.fc-event`.
this.draggableContainer = new Draggable(this.containerEl.nativeElement, {
        itemSelector: '.fc-event',
        eventData(eventEl) {
          const id = eventEl.dataset.id;

          return {
            duration,
            id: currentWorkItem.id,
            title: currentWorkItem.description,
            extendedProps: {
              duration,
              customRender: true,
              data: currentWorkItem,
            },
          };
        }
```

Then, in your test file (Cypress)

```
const eventData = {
      date: new Date(),
      dateStr: new Date().toISOString(),
      draggedEl: {
        dataset: {
          notificationId: '123',
          priority: '0',
          title: 'Test',
        },
      },
      jsEvent: null,
      resource: {
        id: '123',
      },
      event: null,
      oldEvent: null,
    };

cy.get('.fc-event') // selector for the external event I want to drag in the calendar

      .trigger('dragstart')
      .get('.fc-time-grid table tr[data-time="07:00:00"] td.fc-widget-content:nth-child(2)') // selector for where I want to drop the event.
      .trigger('drop', eventData) // this will fire the eventDrop event
```

So, `.trigger('drop', eventData)` will fill the eventDrop info. It is not exactly the same as doing it manually, but works for me.

Caveats:

- I haven't found a way to plan it on another resource (we use the resource scheduling plugin of FullCalendar.io). It does not matter that much, because you can specify it in the evenData (`resource: { id: 'my-resource-id' } }`.
- No visual feedback because the drag mirror is not shown. Not a big problem during e2e testing, but it is a bit of a blackbox now. Maybe this is fixable